# Destroying WebWorkers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, web-worker

Is there a way to destroy HTML5 WebWorkers in JavaScript?

Here's  my situation: I have a web application that generates a decent number of WebWorkers (anywhere between 16 and 32) to optimize some rendering processes.  This process works fine the first few times through, but the page dies when the script is run several times (without reloading the page).  It's the same error I get when I try to spawn a lot (100+) WebWorkers at once, so I'm assuming I running into the same barrier.

When the script runs more than once, the WebWorkers that were instantiated in the first round no longer need to exist; I don't reuse any WebWorker objects.  I would like to destroy the WebWorkers that were created the first time through so that future executions  of the script don't stall while attempting to spawn new WebWorkers.

I've only noticed this problem in Chrome and Firefox; Safari doesn't seem to have this limitation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be able to call this from the main window to immediately terminate a worker:

```
myWorker.terminate();
```

See the full API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Alternatively, you can call `close()` from the worker itself  see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Comment: but it only stops the worker from finishing it's task, the worker's instance is still in memory..

Comment: @vsync I am working with WebWorker instances too. In my case, I need 4 web workers to work on 4 distinct DOM areas that need to be updated every second based on some information that I pass to each web worker that is processed and sent back to the browser. In this use case, should I terminate()/close() each WebWorker after each call, or can I reuse the same one without worrying about performance issues, memory leaks, etc.?

Comment: I don't know the details of how much memory each worker takes and how long it takes to start up/shut down a worker. My guess is that unless your worker is saving state, its memory footprint is minimal. I would also guess that it takes a few milliseconds to start. So, I would think that if performance is primary concern, then keep the workers around and reuse as necessary. But, also, make sure to do performance testing to be sure you know where your bottlenecks are. Also, this doc seems to show some interesting data: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/02/18/web-workers-part-1-performance.html